# Can not connect Apache Ignite on Azure Kuberntes from .net core app

Tags: azure, kubernetes, .net-core, ignite, azure-aks

I am new to Ignite and Kubernetes. I have a.Net Core 3.1 web application which is hosted Azure Linux App Service.

I followed the instructions [(Apache Ignite Instructions Offical Site)](https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/microsoft-azure-deployment) and Apache Ignite could run on Azure Kubernetes. I could create a sample table and read-write actions worked successfully. Here is the screenshot of my success tests on PowerShell.

[Please see the success test](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ly7Py.png)

Now, I try to connect Apache Ignite from my .net core web app but I couldn't make it.
My code is as below. I try to connect with IgniteConfiguration and SpringCfgXml, but both of them getting error.

```
private void Initialize()
{
    var cfg = GetIgniteConfiguration();
    _ignite = Ignition.Start(cfg);
    InitializeCaches();
}

public IgniteConfiguration GetIgniteConfiguration()
{
    var appSettingsJson = AppSettingsJson.GetAppSettings();
    var igniteNodes = appSettingsJson["AppSettings:IgniteNodes"];
    var nodeList = igniteNodes.Split(",");
    var config = new IgniteConfiguration
    {
        Logger = new IgniteLogger(),
        DiscoverySpi = new TcpDiscoverySpi
        {
            IpFinder = new TcpDiscoveryStaticIpFinder
            { 
                Endpoints = nodeList
            },
            SocketTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5)
        },
        IncludedEventTypes = EventType.CacheAll,
        CacheConfiguration = GetCacheConfiguration()
    };
    return config;
}
```

The first error I get:

> Apache.Ignite.Core.Common.IgniteException   HResult=0x80131500
>   Message=Java class is not found (did you set IGNITE_HOME environment
>   variable?):
>   org/apache/ignite/internal/processors/platform/PlatformIgnition
>   Source=Apache.Ignite.Core

Also, I have no idea what I am gonna set for IGNITE_HOME, and username and secret to authentication.

Answer (score 1):

Solution : 
I finally connect the Ignite on Azure Kubernetes.

Here is my connection method.

```
public void TestConnection()
{
    var cfg = new IgniteClientConfiguration
    {
        Host = "MyHost",
        Port = 10800,
        UserName = "user",
        Password = "password"
    };

    using (IIgniteClient client = Ignition.StartClient(cfg))
    {
        var employeeCache1 = client.GetOrCreateCache<int, Employee>(
            new CacheClientConfiguration(EmployeeCacheName, typeof(Employee)));

        employeeCache1.Put(1, new Employee("Bilge Wilson", 12500, 1));
    }
}
```

To find to host IP, user name and client secret please check the below images.

Client Id and Secret
[image]

IP Addresses
[image]

Note: I don't need to set any IGNITE_HOME ana JAVA_HOME variable.

Comment: Yes, this solution is sound, you're much better off connecting with thin client.

Answer (score 0):

[The simplest way](https://apacheignite-net.readme.io/docs/cross-platform-support) is to download Apache Ignite binary distribution (of the same version as one that you use), unzip it to a directory, and point `IGNITE_HOME` environment variable or `IgniteConfiguration.IgniteHome` configuration property to unzipped apache-ignite-n.n.n-bin/ directory absolute path.

We support doing that automatically for Windows-hosted apps but not for Linux-based deployments.

Comment: Thanks @alamar. But my web apps and apache ignite services are working on Azure. Is The method you told still suitable for me?

Comment: Yes, I don't see why not. You need to deploy this directory there.